# Guice field injection not working (returns null)

Tags: java, testing, dependency-injection, frameworks, guice

i am having a problem with null values working with Guice. Nex I show you an example of a similar scenario. **I know field injection is a bad practice, but I want it to work like this for a demo**

I have concrete class named **B** (which is the one I want to inject):

```
class B{

    @Inject
    public B(){}

    public void fooMethod(){
        System.out.println("foo!")
    }
}
```

I have an abstract class named **A**, which has the class **B** (the one I want to inject by field injection):

```
abstract class A{

    @Inject
    protected B b;

}
```

Now another concrete class named **C** that extends **A**:

```
class C extends A{

    public void barMethod(){
        System.out.println("is b null? " + (b==null)); // is true
    }
}
```

My guice configuration is the following:

```
class ConfigModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        // bind(B.class) // I have also tried this
    }

    @Provides
    B getB(){
        return new B();
    }

    @Provides
    C getC(){
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Then I have a test with Spock:

```
@UseModules(ConfigModule)
class Test extends Specification{

    @Inject
    public C c;

    def "test"() {
        // Here goes the test using:
        c.barMethod();
    }       
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you creating `C`?

Comment: Your ConfigModule as it appears is irrelevant, and can be removed with B's `@Inject` constructor. Guice won't fail quietly if B is required but not bound, so to agree with Tavian it really comes down to how you're getting C from Guice. I would assume through a method that `@Provides` a `new C()`, or some way that leaves Guice out of it entirely.

Comment: Hi guys, I have updated the question with more details, I have it like the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what's throwing you off:

```
@Provides
C getC(){
    return new C();
}
```

Delete it. Delete the whole module, in fact—none of the methods you've defined are helping your injection.

---

When you create a `@Provides C` method, Guice assumes that you're creating C just the way you'd like it, and will not populate `@Inject`-annotated fields or call `@Inject`-annotated methods. However, when C has an `@Inject`-annotated or public argumentless constructor, Guice will inspect the object and create it according to its `@Inject` fields and methods, which is the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman! Do you know any resource to learn more about Guice? It is interesting but I found it quite hard...