# Guice & Dropwizard - Field Injection not working - while Constructor Injection does

Tags: kotlin, guice, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

I have a test class that looks something like this
Behind the scenes, we're using *Guice* and *DropwizardAwareModule* to configure the binding and provide instantiated classes/beans.

```
class SomeTest {

companion object {
  @RegisterExtension
  @JvmField
  val app = TestGuiceyAppExtension.forApp(MyServer::class.java)
    .config(configFileName).hooks(GuiceyConfigurationHook {
    builder(it)
  }).create()
}


@Inject
@Named("something")
private lateinit var someClass: SomeClass

}
```

The SomeClass is defined in the following way:

```
class SomeClass(firstClass: FirstClass, secondClass: SecondClass) {

}
```

With no constructor injection.

In a separate DropwizardAwareModule, I define a Provides function that provides 2 possible instances of SomeClass. For example -

```
@Provides
@Named("something")
fun getSomeClass(firstClass: FirstClass, secondClass: SecondClass) {
  return SomeClass(firstClass, secondClass)
}
```

The test class fails to inject SomeClass, claiming it doesn't have a no-args constructor, nor an @Inject annotated constructor, fair enough.

However, if I transform the field injection into a constructor injection, it works flawlessly.

That is - this configuration works well, and the SomeClass instance I provided in the module above, shows up alright.

```
class SomeTest @Inject constructor(@Named("something") someClass: SomeClass) {


}
```

Why is it so? is it because of some limitation in test classes? or is it something to do with @Provides generating an immutable instance, whereas field injection requires mutable objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide a code in which you are configuring `SomeTest` injection. Do you use `requestInjection` or what?

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk Added our call to TestGuiceyAppExtension and added 2 comments about using Guice and DropwizardAwareModule, hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: It seems this is an "expected guice behaviour" (never faced this myself): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43878887/5186390

Comment: @xvik Interesting, thank you :)